# MySQL How to insert new record or update a field depending on whether it exists?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I am trying to implement a rating system where I keep the following two fields in my db table:

rating (the current rating)
num_rates (the number of ratings submitted so far)

```
UPDATE `mytable`
   SET rating=((rating*num_rates)+$theRating)/num_rates, num_rates=num_rates+1
 WHERE uniqueCol='$uniqueCol'
```

the variables are from my PHP code.

So, basically sometimes the row with the uniqueCol does not exist in the DB, so how can I do the above statement if the exists and if it doesn't then do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `mytable`
   SET rating=$theRating, num_rates=1, uniqueCol=$uniqueCol
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

It should look something like that:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (rating, num_rates, uniqueCol)
VALUES ($theRating, 1, $uniqueCol)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  rating=((rating*num_rates)+$theRating)/num_rates,
  num_rates=num_rates+1;
```

Make sure to have a `UNIQUE index` or `PRIMARY KEY` on your `uniqueCol`.